# Understanding Papaparse

Tags: javascript, papaparse

I am trying to understand Papaparse.  I see a lot of examples do something like this

```
var file = evt.target.files[0];

Papa.parse(file, {
    header: true,
    dynamicTyping: true,
    complete: function(results) {
    data = results;
  }
});
```

This is nice and simple, directly parse a file.

However, at the same time I see some examples like so

```
upload (e) {
    const that = this
    const fileToLoad = event.target.files[0]
    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = fileLoadedEvent => {
      Papa.parse(fileLoadedEvent.target.result, {
        header: true,
        complete (results) {
          console.log('complete', results)
          that.doc = JSON.stringify(results.data, null, 2)
        },
        error (errors) {
          console.log('error', errors)
        }
      })
    }
    reader.readAsText(fileToLoad)
  },
```

That is a vuejs function, but I see other examples like this.  So why do some call Papaparse directly, whilst others use a `Filereader` to load the file before parsing?

Just trying to understand the difference between the two approaches?

Thanks

Example using Webworker and Filereader [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100011/using-papa-parse-for-big-csv-files)
Example doing a direct parse [HERE](https://www.joyofdata.de/blog/parsing-local-csv-file-with-javascript-papa-parse/)

Comment: It would be nice if you could also post links for your code sources. In this case, I think the context of code will make more sense.

Comment: Sure, I updated my post with 2 examples.  Maybe Papaparse 4 handles the filereader for me?